# Joining Multiple One-To-Many Tables w/o Duplicate Rows

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join two [one-to-many] tables from a [one-to-one] table and while the query works it produces duplicate or more rows. Please help as I am desperate to get this working. Here is the query in easy format...

```
SELECT a.id, b.*, c.*
FROM tableA a 
LEFT JOIN tableB b
   ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN tableC c
   ON a.id = c.id
WHERE a.id = 12345
```

Comment: Thinking aloud - i would be tempted to make the: 'table b to table a', also the 'table c to table a' as two separate subqueries. Now,  you have 'table a' that is common to both 'sub tables'. It suspect it i possible to outer join those to 'table a' again and you will not get the rows duplicated but you will get null rows. Yes, i know table occurs three times in the output but it should allow you to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I like the idea of subqueries as I was thinking all along that I needed something along that line. Well, more studying to do... subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

If distinct does not work try creating two separate views for tableB and tableC then doing a join on those two views:

```
Create view view_tableB as
SELECT a.id, b.*
FROM tableA a 
LEFT JOIN tableB b
   ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id = 12345;


Create view view_tableC as
SELECT a.id, c.*
FROM tableA a 
LEFT JOIN tableC c
   ON a.id = c.id
WHERE a.id = 12345;


Select * from view_tableB join view_tableC;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I have tried Distinct, Order By and Group By to no avail.

Comment: I just tried that and I still get 25 duplicates of 5 rows.